# How to change multiple buttons text using only one function, tkinter python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, text

I would like to use only one function (self.toggle) for all of my buttons in my GUI instead of doing each for every button. I have tried to change name of self.button only without numbers and then I had text changing on just one button not the one required. Is there simple way to do just one function? I'm just starting with Python. Thanks in advance.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Button

class Application(Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.create_widgets()
    self.number = [1, 2, 3]
    self.mainloop()

def toggle1(self, number):

        if self.button1.config('text')[-1] == f"{number}: ON":
            self.button1.config(text=f"{number}: OFF")
            print("OFF")
        else:
            self.button1.config(text=f"{number}: ON")
            print("ON")

def toggle2(self, number):

        if self.button2.config('text')[-1] == f"{number}: ON":
            self.button2.config(text=f"{number}: OFF")
            print("OFF")
        else:
            self.button2.config(text=f"{number}: ON")
            print("ON")

def toggle3(self, number):

        if self.button3.config('text')[-1] == f"{number}: ON":
            self.button3.config(text=f"{number}: OFF")
            print("OFF")
        else:
            self.button3.config(text=f"{number}: ON")
            print("ON")

def create_widgets(self):
    self.title("application")

    width = 200
    height = 250
    screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
    x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
    y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
    self.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))

    self.button1 = Button(self, text = "1: OFF", command=lambda: self.toggle1(1))
    self.button1.grid(
        row=3, column=0, sticky="w", columnspan=1, padx=0, pady=10)

    self.button2 = Button(self, text = "2: OFF", command=lambda: self.toggle2(2))
    self.button2.grid(
        row=5, column=0, sticky="w", columnspan=1, padx=0, pady=10)

    self.button3 = Button(self, text = "3: OFF", command=lambda: self.toggle3(3))
    self.button3.grid(
        row=7, column=0, sticky="w", columnspan=1, padx=0, pady=10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the button widget to `toggle()` as below:

```py
...
class Application(Tk):
    ...
    def toggle(self, button):
        number, state = button['text'].split(': ')
        state = 'ON' if state == 'OFF' else 'OFF'
        button['text'] = f'{number}: {state}'
        print(number, state)

    def create_widgets(self):
        ...
        self.button1 = Button(self, text="1: OFF", command=lambda: self.toggle(self.button1))
        ...
        self.button2 = Button(self, text="2: OFF", command=lambda: self.toggle(self.button2))
        ...
        self.button3 = Button(self, text="3: OFF", command=lambda: self.toggle(self.button3))
        ...
```